# Gun doesn't zoom out

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem with my weapon's zoom script. I have been stuck on this for hours now. I have visited many sites in hope of solving my problem, but to no avail!

I don't think the problem has anything to do with Unity, but with my script instead. The code works perfectly fine when I zoom in (holding right click), but doesn't zoom out when I release right click and the animation has finished playing. It stays zoomed in! Once the animation has ended and I release right click, the weapon stays zoomed in.

The zoomIn() function works fine, but the gun doesn't zoom out during the zoomOut() function. I know the zoomOut() function works fine, because the camera's FOV resets back to what it was(60), but the animation doesn't rewind (maybe because it's stopped?). I have tried changing the animation's time, changing its speed and rewinding and many other things. If I am fully zoomed in and I zoom in again (I right click once the animation has finished playing), the gun jumps back to its original position and plays the zoom animation again.

The script makes perfect sense to me, so I don't know what is going on or how to fix it!

Below is my code:

```js
 #pragma strict

 var arms : GameObject;
 var zoomed : boolean = false;

 function Update () {
     if (Input.GetMouseButton(1) && zoomed == false) {
         zoomIn();
     }
     if (!Input.GetMouseButton(1)) {
         zoomOut();
     }
 }

 function zoomIn() {
     if (Input.GetMouseButton(1)) {
         animation.Play("zoom");
         camera.main.fieldOfView = 50;
         arms.active = false;
         yield WaitForSeconds(0.3);
         zoomed = true;
     }
 }

 function zoomOut() {
     zoomed = false;
     if (zoomed == false) {
         animation.Rewind("zoom");
         camera.main.fieldOfView = 60;
         arms.active = true;
     }
 }
```

Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use **Animation.Rewind**. This only rewinds the animation, but does not (AFAIK) play the animation in reverse

Try this out instead.

Replace your zoomIn() and zoomOut() methods with the below

```js
function zoomIn() {
    //A speed of 1 means that the animation will play at 1x in the positive timeline
    animation["zoom"].speed = 1;
    //Set the time to the FIRST key frame.
    animation["zoom"].time = 0;
    animation.Play("zoom");
    camera.main.fieldOfView = 50;
    arms.active = false;
    yield WaitForSeconds(0.3);
    zoomed = true;
}

function zoomOut() {
    zoomed = false;
    //A speed of -1 means that the animation will play the animation at 1x speed in reverse
    animation["zoom"].speed = -1;
    //Set the time to the LAST key frame. Replace the number "10" with the time of your last keyframe
    animation["zoom"].time = 10;
    animation.Play("zoom");
    camera.main.fieldOfView = 60;
    arms.active = true;
 }
```

Comment: It didn't work. Thanks for the help, though. I fixed it by playing the animation again and then rewinding it